# In Django REST framework, how do I tell my serializer to update a member field instead of trying to create it from scratch?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, many-to-many, django-serializer

I'm using Django 3 and Python 3.8 along with the Django rest framework.  I have the following model.  Notice the many-to-many relationship with addresses ...

```
class Coop(models.Model):
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    types = models.ManyToManyField(CoopType, blank=False)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    phone = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_phone')
    email = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_email')
    web_site = models.TextField()
```

I have created the following serializers.  I'm having trouble with updating the model so I exluded the create methods for simplicity ...

```
class AddressTypeField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    queryset = Address.objects

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if type(data) == dict:
            locality = data['locality']
            state = None if not re.match(r"[0-9]+", str(locality['state'])) else State.objects.get(pk=locality['state'])
            locality['state'] = state
            locality, created = Locality.objects.get_or_create(**locality)
            data['locality'] = locality
            address = Address.objects.create(**data)
            # Replace the dict with the ID of the newly obtained object
            data = address.pk
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
...


class CoopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    types = CoopTypeSerializer(many=True, allow_empty=False)
    addresses = AddressTypeField(many=True)
    phone = ContactMethodPhoneSerializer()
    email = ContactMethodEmailSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Coop
        fields = '__all__'
    ...

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Coop` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        try:
            coop_types = validated_data['types']
            instance.types.clear()  # Disassociates all  CoopTypes from instance.
            for item in coop_types:
                coop_type, _ = CoopType.objects.get_or_create(**item)
                instance.types.add(coop_type)
        except KeyError:
            pass
        instance.addresses = validated_data.get('addresses', instance.addresses)
        instance.enabled = validated_data.get('enabled', instance.enabled)
        phone = validated_data.pop('phone', {})
        email = validated_data.pop('email', {})
        instance.phone = ContactMethod.objects.create(type=ContactMethod.ContactTypes.PHONE, **phone)
        instance.email = ContactMethod.objects.create(type=ContactMethod.ContactTypes.EMAIL, **email)
        instance.web_site = validated_data.get('web_site', instance.web_site)
        instance.web_site = validated_data.get('web_site', instance.web_site)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

What's the right way to handle updating the address fields of my main Coop model?  When I submit a payload like below (I have IDs included with my address member field objects) ...

```
{"id":927,"types":[{"id":76,"name":"ct"}],"addresses":[{"id":824,"street_number":"","route":"","raw":"","formatted":"4750 N Woodlawn Rd","latitude":null,"longitude":null,"locality":{"id":54,"name":"Chicago","postal_code":"60640","state":19313}}],"phone":{"phone":"3039468888"},"email":{"email":"dave@hello.com"},"name":"Dave Coop","enabled":true,"web_site":"http://www.example.org"}
```

And submit it via PATCH, I get the error below.  Is there some way to tell my serializer to only update the member field if an ID is created instead of trying to create it from scratch each time?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/directory/views.py", line 78, in put
    if serializer.is_valid():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 234, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 433, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 490, in to_internal_value
    validated_value = field.run_validation(primitive_value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 565, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 519, in to_internal_value
    return [
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 520, in <listcomp>
    self.child_relation.to_internal_value(item)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/directory/serializers.py", line 35, in to_internal_value
    address = Address.objects.create(**data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 433, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 782, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 886, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 923, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1377, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '824' for key 'address_address.PRIMARY'")
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `partial=True` in `serializer`

Comment: Gave it a whirl but nothin' doin.